# Seleccionar varias filas alternas en una JTable

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

Al momento que selecciono una fila y le doy click en el boton enviar se graba correctamente pero cuando selecciono varias filas solo se graba una fila, como haria para que se que grabaran todas las filas que selecciono. Comparto una imagen y el codigo con el que grabo y selecciono las filas.

```
protected void btnEnviarActionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //se crea una variable para que contenga la fila seleccionada de la tabla
        int i = tbDocTransferir.getSelectedRow();
        //hacemos una condicion de que si la varialbe i es -1 es que no se ha seleccionado ninguna 
        //fila
        if (i == -1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Seleccione la fila que desea solicitar"); 
        }
        else{
            String codArchivo = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(i, 0);
            String codCentroCosto = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(i, 1);
            String tipoArchivo = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(i, 4);
            String doc = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(i, 6);
            String nivelArchivo = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(i, 8);
            String lote = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(i, 10);
            String fila = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(i, 11);
            String usuarioSolicita = txtUsuarioSolicita.getText();
            String fechaSolicita = txtFechaSolicita.getText();
            Objeto object = (Objeto) cboCentroCostoDestino.getSelectedItem();
            String centroCostoDestino = ((Objeto)object).getCodigo();
            String centroCostoOrigen = txtCodCentroCosto.getText();

            MovimientoArchivoDTO x = new MovimientoArchivoDTO();
            x.setC_c_archivo(codArchivo);
            x.setC_ccosto(codCentroCosto);
            x.setC_ccosto_origen(centroCostoOrigen);
            x.setC_ccosto_destino(centroCostoDestino);
            x.setC_tipo_doc(tipoArchivo);
            x.setC_t_doc(doc);
            x.setC_c_nivel_archivo(nivelArchivo);
            x.setLote(lote);
            x.setFila(fila);
            x.setC_c_usuario_solicita(usuarioSolicita);
            x.setD_dt_solicita(fechaSolicita);
            int estado = xy.RegistrarSolicitudArchivo_SA(x);
            if (estado == 1){
                mensaje("El Documento se solicitó correctamente");
            }
            else
                mensaje("Error en enviar");
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una `JTable` por defecto trabaja en el modo `MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION` si no lo cambias.
Los siguientes modos existen:

- ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION - Puede seleccionar solo un indice
- ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION - puede seleccionar indices consecutivos
- ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION - puede seleccionar sin restricción

Lo que pasa es que usas `tabla.getSelectedRow()` que solamente te devuelve el número de la ultima fila seleccionada. lo que buscas probablemente es:

```
int[] seleccionados = tabla.getSelectedRows();
```

Answer (score 1):

Espero te sirva.

```
class SharedListSelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) { 
        ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel)e.getSource();

        int firstIndex = e.getFirstIndex();
        int lastIndex = e.getLastIndex();
        boolean isAdjusting = e.getValueIsAdjusting(); 
        output.append("Event for indexes "
                      + firstIndex + " - " + lastIndex
                      + "; isAdjusting is " + isAdjusting
                      + "; selected indexes:");

        if (lsm.isSelectionEmpty()) {
            output.append(" <none>");
        } else {
            // Find out which indexes are selected.
            int minIndex = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();
            int maxIndex = lsm.getMaxSelectionIndex();
            for (int i = minIndex; i <= maxIndex; i++) {
                if (lsm.isSelectedIndex(i)) {
                    output.append(" " + i);
                }
            }
        }
        output.append(newline);
        output.setCaretPosition(output.getDocument().getLength());
    }
}
```

Mas informacion:
[How to Write a List Selection Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)